# Tomcat timeout when using SSL

Tags: tomcat, ssl, encryption

I'm having an issue with Tomcat 6. For some reason Tomcat does not answer the Client Hello SSL message when using Chrome or Firefox (so the browser eventually times out), but it works perfectly on Internet Explorer. The strange part is that this doesn't always happen; it depends on the machine in which Tomcat is running (on some machines it works and on some others it doesn't).

Using a packer sniffer I compared the different Client Hello messages and I was able to track the problem down to the 0x0033 cipher suite (TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA). If the browser specifies it as an accepted cipher suite, then the server might hang (depending on the machine on which it is running). Internet Explorer does not specify it as an accepted cipher suite, so the server works correctly, but Chrome and Firefox do, so that's when the problem appears (actually I think that the server eventually answers the Client Hello message, but it takes so long that about 99,99% of the time the browser times out).

I have a workaround for this, and it is to disable this cipher suite on the browser. I guess I can disable the cipher suite on Tomcat also, but I'm trying to avoid that. I'm actually trying to find out why it hangs on the first place. Note that I haven't really found any pattern on the machines in which the problem appears, except that they are all Windows machines.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only idea I can suggest - custom crypto soft installed on those windows machines, that somehow registers it's security provider for some of the ciphersuites (e.g. using endorsed libs). So java calls external implementation of this ciphersuite and hangs on it for some reason. I never encountered this myself but hear such story once. Not so probable idea I'm afraid.

Othrewise this ciphersuite looks absolutely sane, just tried it on linux.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. What kind of crypto soft could cause this? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @Paul, sorry, I have no concrete examples for this, only idea